# Database Design for Addresses with Various Types

Tags: sql, database, object-oriented-database

I'm designing my first database, and am considering 1 of 2 ways to create the "Address" table:

1. Create "Address" table with following columns:
   PartyID, Address Type, Street, Apt/Suite, City, State, Zip/Postal Code

The advantage I see here is that a PartyID can be associated with multiple addresses, but associating a PartyID with an Order might not define clearly the address used for that order?

Or...

2. Create "Address" table in following format: AddressID, AddressType, Street, Apt/Suite, City, State, Zip/Postal Code

The advantage here is that I can assign a specific AddressID to each Contact/Organization (PartyID) table, but am not sure how this might affect an order that has multiple addresses (Shipping vs Billing).

Can anyone tell me which of the two designs is the better approach, or if there is a 3rd and better approach that I should use?

Thanks for the help! I'm enjoying the process, but don't want to get hung up longer than i have to.

Comment: Having a separate Addresses table assumes an address can be used for multiple parties or a party can have 2 or more addresses. If each address associates with only 1 party and each Party will have only 2 addresses (Shipping and Billing), could just have all address fields (2 sets for Shipping and Billing) in Party table. Otherwise, maybe two address ID fields in Party table: Shipping and Billing.

Comment: "Normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works." There really isn't a single 'right' answer. Learn rdbms concepts and build what works best for you.

Comment: Did you tag this with "object-oriented-database" because you are open to the possibility of using one, or are you committed to using a relational database?

Comment: @djhallx I am definitely open to OOD, because I think there would be a lot of value in structuring this way, considering our data (healthcare). I'm probably being overzealous thinking I can pull it off on my first database, but I'm thinking along those lines as I build.